# Fill selection regions with the average color inside them

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, pixelation

I'm trying to design stained glass. Photoshop has the "Stained Glass" filter, but I need a bit more flexibility than it allows.

I've used it to create the [came](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Came) structure:

[image: came structure]

Now I want to take my original image:

[image: original image]

And **color the regions according to it, such that there is only one color per region**.

Here's the expected result:

[image: desired result]

Of course, I know I can select each region individually and posterize it, but I was hoping for something that made use of the computer a bit more.

If this is not possible within Photoshop, I'm happy to use any other graphic software for the task

Comment: Dude that's possible right inside the Stained Glass filter when used right on the image itself. Isn't that what you want?